# i don't understand that this training code for android studio

Tags: android

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String SIGNUP_EMAIL = "com.example.myapplication.SIGNUP_EMAIL";
    public static final String SIGNUP_PASSWORD = "com.example.myapplication.SIGNUP_PASSWORD";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void signup(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignupResultActivity.class);

        EditText signup_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
        EditText signup_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_password);

        String email = signup_email.getText().toString();
        String password = signup_password.getText().toString();

        intent.putExtra(SIGNUP_EMAIL, email);
        intent.putExtra(SIGNUP_PASSWORD, password);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

```java
public static final String SIGNUP_EMAIL = null;
public static final String SIGNUP_PASSWORD = null;
```

why should not use "null" in this code?

if you put SIGNUP_EMAIL=null and SIGNUP_PASSWORD=null, is not working

Answer (score 4):

`Intent` is similar to `Map`, the value of these variables are the keys to index this map. Not only those keys must be non-null, but they must be different from each other.

Quoted from [Start another activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity) (emphasis mine):

> The `putExtra()` method adds the `EditText`'s value to the intent. An Intent can carry data types as key-value pairs called *extras*. Your key is a public constant `EXTRA_MESSAGE` because **the next activity uses the key to retrieve the text value**. It's a good practice to define keys for intent extras using your app's package name as a prefix. **This ensures the keys are unique**, in case your app interacts with other apps.

Answer (score 1):

`SIGNUP_EMAIL` and `SIGNUP_PASSWORD` are not default values for mail and password, they are string keys used to pass ang get the values, so they cannot be `null`.

They are public constants so that the intent can know them to retreive the value.

EDIT: note that the strings are declared `final` so that the keys cannot be changed afterwards, having a property declared `final` with a `null` value should have raised a mental flag as it is a bit useless..

Answer (score 0):

when you want to pass a data from one activity to another one you should use intent.putExtra(name,data);
first parameter is the name and second is data that you want to send
you can use any string that you want for name parameter but it cant be null
in second activity you use it to get data from first activity by this code :
intent.getStringExtra(name)

Answer (score -1):

You can use any unique string to map the values. Null wont work but "null" will work. But keep one thing in mind that for two different values you need to assign different keys also.
Like this:

```
    public static final String SIGNUP_EMAIL = "null";
    public static final String SIGNUP_PASSWORD = "Null";
```